# Fill a string array with words from a file

Tags: arrays, string, fstream

I am given a file with about ten lines and I need to fill a string array with all the items (except for the first) from a given line.

If the text file looked like:

```
Word abc def
Ghi jkl mno
Pqr stu vwx
```

And if i wanted to fill a string array with items from line 2, it needs to look like:

```
(jkl mno)
```

How do I access a certain line in the file and fill the string array?

This is what I have so far

```
string str;
getline(infile, str);
while(!(infile.eof())&&(str[0]!= firstLetterOfLine))
{
    getline(infile, str);
}
```

I believe that this will give me the correct line of the file. Now, I am trying to figure out how to add each word into a string array.

My plan is to make substrings and send those to array[i] for every i less than the size of the array, but I am not sure how to choose the positions for the beginning and end of the substring. I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me, just a hint in the correct direction.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to do your homework, but to help and guide you. Please share your code.

Comment: Are you looking for how to [split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)?

Comment: I think so. Is there a way to do it without vectors though?